# Adding GooglePlayServicesInterstitial to MoPub SDK

Tags: android, google-play-services, mopub

My Android project needs to reference GooglePlayServicesInterstitial.java to show AdMob ads via the MoPub SDK.

[Following these instructions](https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/android/google-play-services), I'm trying I'm trying to drag the file into where it says but it won't let me:

[image]

So how exactly do I import this file into my project so the MoPub SDK can reference it?

Answer (score 1):

try this instead. https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-Third-Party-Ad-Networks

specifically the part you are looking for is

> Integrating using the SDK Source The extras/com/mopub/mobileads folder
>   contains a set of custom events; simply copy the ones you want into
>   com.mopub.mobileads into your app’s src/ directory.

so you will have something like the following: -

[image]

Note: you copy the file into your SRC directory, not into the Lib directory